# ZipCode Algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm

I have to write a function that takes in an array of zipcodes and only returns the ones that do not produce super overlappy visualizations if a circle was drawn around the zipcode of a fixed radius. So basically my function takes in array of zipcodes and a radius variable.

What are some algorithms I can use to produce non overlappy maps?

Here is a messed up visualization:

[image]

Here is a correct one.

[image]

One algorithm that I came up was to basically loop through the zip code array one zip at a time and then determine the distance to other zipcodes in the array center using the provided lat / lon coordinates and then finding all the zips that are intersected. However As you can imagine that it is not a perfect implementation as some overlap is OK and also my algorithm would assume perfect circles.

Is there a common sense algorithm that I am missing? Just trying to learn.

Comment: Consider this: zip codes radii that do not overlap may leave vast areas of some zip codes uncovered. In addition, many zip code regions are highly oddly shaped.

Comment: Not true. If that is the case then we would not have an algorithm tag which is exactly what the OP asked for.

Comment: What do you mean @jini? Which part of what I said is not true?

Comment: Step 1 is to precisely define what *"super overlappy"* means. You can't write code to accomplish a task before you've defined what the task is. Specifically, the upper right corner of your second image looks *"super overlappy"* to me.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard The OP asked for help in coming up with an algorithm which is a common thing on SO and henceforth there is a algorithm tag. Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm  How are they different? People quite commonly ask for algorithm help without posting any code.

Comment: I still fail to see how what you're saying addresses my comment @jini I will say the question is far too broad and there are too many variables the OP is leaving out though.

Comment: https://www.zipcodeapi.com/